# How can I phrase a question about a theoretical event in the past, which cannot happen anymore?

Tags: differences, sentence, past-tense

I'll try to give some specific examples, as this one is rather difficult to explain.

Example 1: Imagine you have been attending a kindergarten in Canada. Now you are 30 years old, so you won't go to kindergarten again, but I want to ask you whether you would be happier today, if you were attending a US kindergarten in the past. Would it be like this?

> Would you like to have been attending a US kindergarten?

Example 2: You have been brought up by a stepfather. Now you are an adult, so nobody is, nor will be bringing you up anymore. But yet, I want to ask, whether you would be happier, if it were your real father who brought you up. Would it be like this?

> Would you like to have been brought up by your real father?

Alternatives, or how are they different?

> Would you have wanted to attend a US kindergarten?
>
> Would you have wanted to be attending a US kindergarten?
>
> Would you have wanted to be brought up by your real father?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examples 1 and 2 both correctly accomplish what you want them to. In example 1, you could be slightly more concise by rephrasing it as

> Would you like to have *attended* a US kindergarten?

The alternatives all ask the same slightly different question. Whereas examples 1 and 2 ask the person whether he, **in the present moment**, thinks he would have been better off had his childhood been different, the alternatives ask the person whether he, **when he was a child**, would have preferred those different situations. The key difference between examples 1 and 2 on the one hand, and the alternatives on the other, is the use of the present tense *like* and the past tense *wanted*.

Comment: I agree totally with your distinction, but find it interesting that *Would you rather have...* seems to me to cover both equally. Which I feel practically invites the other party to say whether their feeling about the matter has changed over time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I hear/see *would you rather have* used that way occasionally, but it sounds imprecise to me.

Comment: I can hardly disagree! The point of my post was to say it *covers both equally*, which I think by definition makes it 'imprecise'. There are potentially two different questions which could be asked, each with a variety of valid, unambiguous phrasings. *Would you rather have...* is common enough, and allows the hearer to choose which to answer if he wants.

Answer (score 3):

I would phrase these using the word *rather* with the present perfect tense:

> Would you rather have attended a US kindergarten?
>
> Would you rather have been brought up by your real father?

You can also phrase these with *like to*, though the sentence becomes somewhat more convoluted:

> I would like to have learned a foreign language when I was young.

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase the first condition something like:

> Do you think that you would be happier now if you had attended kindergarten in the US?

...and the second like:

> Would you be happier now if you had been raised by your real father?

or

> Would you be happier now if you were raised by your real father?

---

All five of the examples in the question are grammatically correct, although some are a bit confusing, but there are shades of differences in their meanings.  For instance,

> Would you like to have been attending a US kindergarten?

is different than `Would you like to have attended a US kindergarten?`  The former goes back to the past and asks the question as if the past were now the present.  The latter asks, from the present, with a view to the past.